# Problems with fluid simulation not rendering

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have been trying for the past few days to render my fluid simulation. Everything is perfect and I love what it will be but when I render out the animation the animation is just the floating liquid domain and no motion. Could someone help?

Comment: Have you baked the animation?

Comment: yes, I can see the fluid simulation in the wireframe but when I render its just the first frame floating.